# In WPF C# Application, a Listbox Binding Source directory includes '#', but the app can't load it

Tags: c#, directory, binding, listbox, special-characters

"#" won't work as a source directory name.

I'm creating an app with ListBox to open an xml file using binding in WPF. But, I found that even if it is possible to open in code as XElement, it is not possible to bind to ListBox Source because my source location contains "#" in it.

ex)Source='file:///D:/Users/username/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/C#\Windows Presentation Foundation\ListViewBinding\ListViewBinding\bin\Debug\Teams.xml' WebException:'System.Net.WebException: 'D:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\C' cannot find a file.

I tried to remove # and changed it from "C#" to "Csharp", then it works. So "#" was definitely the problem maker.

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewBinding" xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" x:Class="ListViewBinding.MainWindow" mc:Ignorable="d" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="teamItemTemplate">
        <Label Content="{Binding XPath=Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
 <Grid>
    <!--ListBox-->
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Name="TeamData" Source="Teams.xml" XPath="Teams/Team" />
    </Grid.DataContext>

   <ListBox x:Name="TeamsListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Height="79" Margin="26,166,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=TeamData}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource teamItemTemplate}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >

  </ListBox>
 </Grid>
</Window>
```

And Teams.xml is as follows - This sample is just for test purpose.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Teams xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Team>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>Arizona Cardinals</Name>
    <Conference>NFC West</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>Atlanta Falcons</Name>
    <Conference>NFC South</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <Name>Baltimore Ravens</Name>
    <Conference>AFC North</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>4</Id>
    <Name>Buffalo Bills</Name>
    <Conference>AFC East</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>5</Id>
    <Name>Carolina Panthers</Name>
    <Conference>NFC South</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>6</Id>
    <Name>Chicago Bears</Name>
    <Conference>NFC North</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>7</Id>
    <Name>Cincinnati Bengals</Name>
    <Conference>AFC North</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>8</Id>
    <Name>Cleveland Browns</Name>
    <Conference>AFC North</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>9</Id>
    <Name>Dallas Cowboys</Name>
    <Conference>NFC East</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>10</Id>
    <Name>Denver Broncos</Name>
    <Conference>AFC West</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>11</Id>
    <Name>Detroit Lions</Name>
    <Conference>NFC North</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>12</Id>
    <Name>Green Bay Packers</Name>
    <Conference>NFC North</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>13</Id>
    <Name>Houston Texans</Name>
    <Conference>AFC South</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>14</Id>
    <Name>Indianapolis Colts</Name>
    <Conference>AFC South</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>15</Id>
    <Name>Jacksonville Jaguars</Name>
    <Conference>AFC South</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>16</Id>
    <Name>Kansas City Chiefs</Name>
    <Conference>AFC West</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>17</Id>
    <Name>Miami Dolphins</Name>
    <Conference>AFC East</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>18</Id>
    <Name>Minnesota Vikings</Name>
    <Conference>NFC North</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>19</Id>
    <Name>New England Patriots</Name>
    <Conference>AFC East</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>20</Id>
    <Name>New Orleans Saints</Name>
    <Conference>NFC South</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>21</Id>
    <Name>New York Giants</Name>
    <Conference>NFC East</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>22</Id>
    <Name>New York Jets</Name>
    <Conference>AFC East</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>23</Id>
    <Name>Oakland Raiders</Name>
    <Conference>AFC West</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>24</Id>
    <Name>Philadelphia Eagles</Name>
    <Conference>NFC East</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>25</Id>
    <Name>Pittsburgh Steelers</Name>
    <Conference>AFC North</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>26</Id>
    <Name>San Diego Chargers</Name>
    <Conference>AFC West</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>27</Id>
    <Name>San Francisco 49ers</Name>
    <Conference>NFC West</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>28</Id>
    <Name>St. Louis Rams</Name>
    <Conference>NFC West</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>29</Id>
    <Name>Seattle Seahawks</Name>
    <Conference>NFC West</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>30</Id>
    <Name>Tampa Bay Buccaneers</Name>
    <Conference>NFC South</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>31</Id>
    <Name>Tennessee Titans</Name>
    <Conference>AFC South</Conference>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <Id>32</Id>
    <Name>Washington Redskins</Name>
    <Conference>NFC East</Conference>
  </Team>
</Teams>
```

in cs code, I tried to print some folder and file locations as follows.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
        Uri uri = new Uri(appPath + @"\Teams.xml");
        Console.WriteLine(@"Current URI Directory : " + uri);
        TeamData.Source = uri;

        Console.WriteLine(@"Current Directory: " + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        Console.WriteLine(@"source = " + TeamData.Source);

        }
```

I expect to use an xml source located in "C#" folders like "D:\Users...\c#...\Teams.xml".

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem here is that you're trying to create a URI using the wrong syntax. By including the `file:///` schema in your URI text, you are promising the `System.Uri` class that you are going to provide a valid URI, when in fact you haven't.

There are many different ways to work around this.

The simplest is to use `%23` instead of `#` where you want a hash character (number sign). This is the correct escaping for characters that are otherwise invalid for URIs, like the `#` character.

E.g.:

```xml
<XmlDataProvider x:Name="TeamData" Source="file:///D:/Users/username/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/C%23\Windows Presentation Foundation/ListViewBinding/ListViewBinding/bin/Debug/Teams.xml" XPath="Teams/Team" />
```

Ironically, one of the other ways around this is to just not include the `file:///` component in the path, and provide a regular Windows path. While not encouraged, the .NET `System.Uri` class does support automatic interpretation of Windows file paths for strings passed without a schema.

E.g.:

```xml
<XmlDataProvider x:Name="TeamData" Source="D:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\C#\Windows Presentation Foundation\ListViewBinding\ListViewBinding\bin\Debug\Teams.xml" XPath="Teams/Team" />
```

That would've worked just fine.

All that said, my preferred alternatives look very little like either of the above. The first would be to embed the XML as a resource in the program, and just load it from a resource URI. A plain string would work, or you can use the `pack:` schema.

Then you're not having to deal with the file system at all.

If you really want an external file, another alternative would be to create a view model object to do the work for you. Provide settable properties for the XML file path, and the XPath for the XML, then in the view model any time either of those properties change, set another property that returns an `XmlDataProvider` object where the `Source` and `XPath` properties have been set to the existing view model properties. Then you can just bind the `ListBox.ItemsSource` property directly to your view model's `XmlDataProvider` property (i.e. as `ItemsSource={Binding XmlDataProvider.Data}` where it's assumed the property name in the view model is `XmlDataProvider` — note that the binding path needs to include the `Data` property of the `XmlDataProvider` object, since that's the actual bindable data).

One nice thing about that approach is that it makes it a lot easier to deal with relative paths, since normally `XmlDataProvider` attempts to treat things that look like relative paths as if they were resource names instead. It also gives you more control over the binding process, in case there's additional customization you want to do (e.g. including additional search paths for relative paths, that sort of thing).

Of course, the downside is that there's more code. But most of it is boilerplate, and the rest is less likely to become a maintenance challenge the way raw file paths in the XAML might be.

Comment: I am mildly curious as to why you are suggesting replacing a `#` with the hex encoding of a space.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: wish I knew. sorry, fixed now. I think maybe my fingers are so used to typing encoding for spaces, that when presented with something new, they just refused. thanks for pointing the error out.